# Javascript random numbers for different <li>

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have many `<li>` with different height and width. I want to generate random numbers for every list style. For example 10 list styles have different `innerHTML` numbers inside. Please correct me if I am wrong.

```
function getNumber() {
    var minNumber = 0;
    var maxNumber = 10;
    var randomnumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * (maxNumber + 1) + minNumber);
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        $('ul li').html(randomnumber);
    }
    return false;
}
```

Please guide me or give me advice. Thanks.

Comment: You have a logic issue with your number generation. `(maxNumber + 1)` should be `(maxNumber - minNumber + 1)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's the right way to do it. 
Running the code when the DOM is fully loaded with $() and maybe putting the logic of random number generation in a different function for better reusability.
You can copy-paste the code above to a text file to test it.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            function getRandomNumber(minNumber, maxNumber){
                return Math.floor(Math.random() * (maxNumber + 1) + minNumber);
            }
            $(function(){
                var minNumber = 0;
                var maxNumber = 10;
                $("ul li").each(function(){
                    $(this).html(getRandomNumber(minNumber,maxNumber));
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <ul>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
        </ul>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: explicit iteration is not required

Comment: It's not required but makes the code really more readable and debuggable. Imho

Answer (score 2):

The main issue with your code is that you assign the same random number to all the `li` elements in each iteration of the loop. Instead you should loop over each `li` element and generate a new random number in each iteration. Try this:

```
function getNumber() {
    $('ul li').each(function() {
        var minNumber = 0;
        var maxNumber = 10;
        var randomnumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * (maxNumber + 1) + minNumber);
        $(this).html(randomnumber);
    });
}
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Lu61gkz8/)

Comment: and what if i use specific number like 1, 53, 49, 80, 68 fixed number to all my list style.

Comment: The explicit iteration here is not necessary